# Debugging : Keras+tensorflow code to create sequential model crashing with message "Your session crashed for an unknown reason" on Google colab

Tags: tensorflow, debugging, keras, crash, google-colaboratory

While running the following code on Google colab with 'GPU' runtime (as one of my custom layers performs tensorflow.fft using GPU), my session is crashing -

```
fc2_shape = 32*32

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Flatten(input_shape=(32, 32, 2)))
model.add(layers.Dense(fc2_shape, activation='tanh'))
model.add(layers.Dense(fc2_shape, activation='tanh'))
model.add(layers.Reshape((32, 32, 1)))
model.add(conv2d_layer(num_features=32, kernel_size=5, type_conv="complex"))
model.add(layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(conv2d_layer(num_features=32, kernel_size=5, type_conv="complex", kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.0001)))
model.add(layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(complex_conv_transpose_layer(num_features=1, kernel_size=9, strides=1))

model.summary()
```

It crashes with the message "Your session crashes. Automatically restarting.. Your session restarted after a crash. Debugging.. Your session crashed for an unknown reason. View runtime log"
\newline

The runtime logs are shared below. Could I get some help in understanding what might be causing the crash, as there is not even an error message, but only warnings in the log. Tried many methods suggested for few warnings in the log, but none seem to work. Need to figure out the exact cause. Thanks.

```
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:25 AM    WARNING WARNING:root:kernel 96640b1f-78c4-4aee-8612-299bbd2a4d8d restarted
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:25 AM    INFO    KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:20 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:20.430989: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:20 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:20.256096: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 13960 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla T4, pci bus id: 0000:00:04.0, compute capability: 7.5)
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:20 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:20.256008: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:39] Overriding allow_growth setting because the TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH environment variable is set. Original config value was 0.
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:20 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:20.255209: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:20 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:20.254277: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:20 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:20.253280: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:20 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:20.247860: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 0: N
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:20 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:20.247846: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267] 0
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:20 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:20.247794: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:16 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:16.208463: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:16 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:16.205616: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:16 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:16.204824: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:16 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:16.203940: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:16 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:16.203862: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:16 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:16.203843: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:16 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:16.203825: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:16 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:16.203806: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:16 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:16.203787: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:16 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:16.203768: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.10
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:16 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:16.203743: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:16 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:16.203699: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:16 AM    WARNING coreClock: 1.59GHz coreCount: 40 deviceMemorySize: 14.73GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 298.08GiB/s
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:16 AM    WARNING pciBusID: 0000:00:04.0 name: Tesla T4 computeCapability: 7.5
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:16 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:16.203627: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties:
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:16 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:16.202836: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:16 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:16.202313: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:16 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:16.201374: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:16 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:16.197656: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:16 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:16.196404: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:16 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:16.196182: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:15 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:15.708027: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:15 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:15.691252: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:15 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:15.439674: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:15 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:15.390009: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:15 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:15.274378: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.10
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:15 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:15.274194: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:14 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:14.935005: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:14 AM    WARNING coreClock: 1.59GHz coreCount: 40 deviceMemorySize: 14.73GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 298.08GiB/s
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:14 AM    WARNING pciBusID: 0000:00:04.0 name: Tesla T4 computeCapability: 7.5
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:14 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:14.934938: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties:
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:14 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:14.933915: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:14 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:14.866772: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:14 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:14.865367: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:14 AM    WARNING tcmalloc: large alloc 1228800000 bytes == 0x14210000 @ 0x7f536abaa1e7 0x7f53620a841e 0x7f53620f8c2b 0x7f53620f8cc8 0x7f53621b4d19 0x7f53621b7dec 0x7f53622d6ddf 0x7f53622dcf15 0x7f53622ded9d 0x7f53622e0476 0x5a48ec 0x5a4fb8 0x7f53621bf438 0x59c9f0 0x50ea2d 0x507be4 0x5161c5 0x50a12f 0x50beb4 0x507be4 0x509900 0x50a2fd 0x50beb4 0x507be4 0x509900 0x50a2fd 0x50cc96 0x507be4 0x508ec2 0x594a01 0x59fd0e
Jan 12, 2021, 9:02:06 AM    WARNING 2021-01-12 03:32:06.977597: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
Jan 12, 2021, 9:01:54 AM    INFO    Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel 96640b1f-78c4-4aee-8612-299bbd2a4d8d
Jan 12, 2021, 9:01:52 AM    INFO    Kernel started: 96640b1f-78c4-4aee-8612-299bbd2a4d8d
Jan 12, 2021, 9:00:04 AM    INFO    Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
Jan 12, 2021, 9:00:04 AM    INFO    http://172.28.0.2:9000/
Jan 12, 2021, 9:00:04 AM    INFO    The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
Jan 12, 2021, 9:00:04 AM    INFO    0 active kernels
Jan 12, 2021, 9:00:04 AM    INFO    Serving notebooks from local directory: /
Jan 12, 2021, 9:00:04 AM    INFO    google.colab serverextension initialized.
Jan 12, 2021, 9:00:04 AM    INFO    Writing notebook server cookie secret to /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
Jan 12, 2021, 9:00:04 AM    WARNING Config option `delete_to_trash` not recognized by `ColabFileContentsManager`.
```

Comment: Have you added something to change TF config such as, config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True.

Comment: No, I haven't made any changes to tf config

Answer (score 0):

This generally happens when you use all the RAM available on google colab since it can't handle very big datasets. You could try upgrading the RAM or use different services.

Try [Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/machine-learning/), [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/) or [Google Cloud Services](https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-vm)

All of them have pretty good machine learning products but are all paid. Another alternative is running it locally on Jupyter.

Comment: But the RAM usage is not increasing upto maximum limit before crashing. Also, there are several warnings apart from the large alloc one in the runtime log. I wish to understand from the log what caused the crash.

Comment: this is not the issue, it would say in log crashed to ram usage but it seem not the case

Comment: @psj I'm not sure what it might be then. But maybe try running it locally on a Jupyter notebook and see if you hit a similar error. If so, then the problem might not be with google colab.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to run on local jupyter notebook to get errors reported in the log, unlike colab which is just crashing without giving a proper error log.